# Working with increased precision of irrational numbers in python

Tags: python, precision

I am attempting to do a [continued fraction derivation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of irrational numbers, e.g. sqrt(13), with Python. I have obtained a pretty good solution which is accurate for the first 10 or so iterations:

1. Set the original number as current remainder
2. Append floor of current remainder to list of coefficients
3. Define new remainder as reciprocal of current remainder minus floor
4. Go to step 2 unless new remainder is 0

This works very well, except for later iterations, where the `float` precision is producing erroneous coefficients. Once a single coefficient is off, the remaining will automatically be as well.

My question is therefore if there is a way to treat irrational numbers, e.g. sqrt(13), like placeholders (for later substitution) or in a more precise manner?

My current code is as below:

```
import math


def continued_fraction(x, upper_limit=30):
    a = []
    # should in fact iterate until repetitive cycle is found 
    for i in range(upper_limit):
        a.append(int(x))
        x = 1.0/(x - a[-1])
    return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print continued_fraction(math.sqrt(13))
```

With the resulting output:

```
[3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 2, 1, 4, 2]
```

And I know for a fact, that the resulting output should be 3, followed by infinite repetitions of the cycle (1, 1, 1, 1, 6), as per [Project Euler Problem 64](https://projecteuler.net/problem=64) (which I'm trying to solve).

Comment: You could try the `Decimal` class from the `decimal` module

Comment: @slezica Thanks. That helps quite a bit, but errors still occur beginning at coefficients ~15-30 occasionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any such placeholders in Python.

However, you may consider using [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) which will increase the precision of your math operations but will never guarantee *infinite repetitions of the cycle*. Why? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

The following modification to your code provides correct results for this run up until `upper_limit=45`:

```
import math
from decimal import Decimal


def continued_fraction(x, upper_limit=30):
    a = []
    # should in fact iterate until repetitive cycle is found 
    for i in range(upper_limit):
        a.append(int(x))
        x = Decimal(1.0)/(x - a[-1])
    return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (continued_fraction(Decimal(13).sqrt()))
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you believe it is correct up until upper_limit=45?

Comment: I tested the code and it gave in after `45`, do you have something different?

Comment: Alright. At sqrt(557) it breaks at 31. I was hoping you had some mathematical argument based on actual precision, etc.

Comment: Not quite. The results will vary for different inputs

Answer (score 1):

You might cast an eye over https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Python. It uses the Fractions and Itertools modules.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Marius Becceanu has released [an algorithm for the specific continued fraction of sqrt(n)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151221205104/http://web.math.princeton.edu/mathlab/jr02fall/Periodicity/mariusjp.pdf), which is iterative and really nice. This algorithm does not require use of any floating points.